# my code is not working: Error 424 and error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that has 3 worksheets called, statistics, geography and economics and there are student names/ ids there. I wrote a userform with a textbox and 3 option buttons (statistics, geography and economics) and two command buttons called search and cancel. When you write a name on the textbox and choose one of the option buttons, it will search for the name on the chosen worksheet (which was given in the user form as option buttons). if the name is found then I added a label that will notify its cell address, and if it is not found it will say that the name wasnt found. and when I click cancel it will give me as a message box all the names that weren't found while searching (I used an array to do so). And this is the code I wrote:

```
Dim s(1 To 20) As String, count As Integer


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wsheet As String
    If OptStat = True Then wsheet = OptStat.Caption 'OptStat.Caption = Statistics - it's the name of the worksheet called Statistics
    If OptGeo = True Then wsheet = OptGeo.Caption 'OptGeo.Caption = Geography - it's the name of the worksheet called Geography
    If OptEco = True Then wsheet = OptEco.Caption 'OptEco.caption = Economics - it's the name of the worksheet called Economics
    Worksheets(wsheet).Select

    Set r = Cells.Find(TextBox1.Text, Range("a1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
    If r Is Nothing Then
        count = count + 1
        s(count) = TextBox1.Text & "in " & wsheet
        Label2.Caption = TextBox1.Text & " is not found in " & wsheet
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Address = r.Address
        If TextBox1.Text = r.Value Then
            r.Activate
            Label2.Caption = TextBox1.Text & " found in worksheet " & wsheet & " on cell " & Address
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        Else
            r = Cells.FindNext(r)
            Do While r.Address <> a
                If TextBox1.Text = r.Value Then
                    r.Activate
                    Label2.Caption = TextBox1.Text & " found in worksheet " & wsheet & " on cell " & Address
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    r = Cells.FindNext(r)
                End If
            Loop
            If r.Address = a Then
                count = count + 1
                s(count) = TextBox1.Text & "in " & wsheet
                Label2.Caption = TextBox1.Text & " not founf in " & wsheet
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
    Dim names As String
    names = "The Following names are missing" & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To count
        names = names & s(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i
    count = 0
    Worksheets(1).Select
    MsgBox (names)
End Sub
```

I have two problems with the code, maybe someone can tell me what the problem is. The first problem, I might have, for example the name Tomphson on cell a1 and the name Tom at a2 and I am looking for the name Tom, so searching for tom will give me the cell tomphson first. So I used while loop to take care of that. However it gives me the error 424 object required.
The second problem is with the array. I am trying to print all the names that werent found (as a msgbox) but when ever it goes in the for loop that I wrote in commandbutton2 command, it gives me error 9 subscript out of range.
I've been sitting on this for a while, but I couldn't find what the problem is.  I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few modifications can simplify your code and make it work as desired.

1- You dont need to do a loop to find a whole match for the name, you can use `xlWhole` parameter instead of `xlPart`.

2- Before adding a new name to your array `s`, check if the upper bound is already reached.

3- for button 2, dont unload the form before computing the message, because the array `s` is a member of the form, so if you unload it, the array is no longer valid in memory.

This modification of your code should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wsheet As String
    If OptStat = True Then wsheet = OptStat.Caption 'OptStat.Caption = Statistics - it's the name of the worksheet called Statistics
    If OptGeo = True Then wsheet = OptGeo.Caption 'OptGeo.Caption = Geography - it's the name of the worksheet called Geography
    If OptEco = True Then wsheet = OptEco.Caption 'OptEco.caption = Economics - it's the name of the worksheet called Economics

    Set r = Worksheets(wsheet).Cells.Find(TextBox1.text, Range("a1"), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
    '                                                                             ^^^^^^^^
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto r
        Label2.Caption = TextBox1.text & " found in worksheet " & wsheet & " on cell " & r.address
        TextBox1.text = ""
    Else
        If Count < UBound(s) Then ' <-- Check before adding a name to array
            Count = Count + 1
            s(Count) = TextBox1.text & " in " & wsheet
        End If
        Label2.Caption = TextBox1.text & " not found in " & wsheet
        TextBox1.text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim names As String
    names = "The Following names are missing" & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To Count
        names = names & s(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i
    Count = 0
    Unload Me ' <--- here, not before, we still needed the array s
    Worksheets(1).Select
    MsgBox (names)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The Xlwhole thing actually made my code much shorter than what it was! Can you explain why first writing unload me command made a problem (9 subscript out of range) error? I defined the array for the whole userform (at the start of the page) so it shouldn't matter if I first close the userform then execute commands no? By the way I wanted to write a code that will expand my array in case i reached the upper bound by Redim preserve s(1 to count+20) but it didn't let me, do you know why this wouldn't work? Thanks!

Comment: @mathstackuser123 you are welcome, glad to help :). Concerning `Unload Me`, the runtime when it unloads a usefrform it reclaims its memory, making its member variables (your array) not valid anymore. As for the second question, it surprises me, I need to see where and how you're doing this `Redim`. I suggest that you make sure about it post then post a question, it is worth it IMO.

Comment: Notice by the way, that you *can* unhide the form using `Me.Hide` instead of `Unload Me`, and in this case the data of the form remains valid.